Не загружаются ScriptableObjects с помощью Resources.LoadAll<T>("")
Пытаюсь сделать загрузку ScriptableObjects с типом CardInfo:
CardInfo[] allCardsList;
allCardsList = Resources.LoadAll<CardInfo>("");

Но массив поитогу пустой. Хотя папка Resources существует, и внутри нее есть нужные мне файлы. В чем может быть проблема?


По описанию, это должно работать. Убедитесь, что CardInfo отнаследован от ScriptableObject'а. И, если есть несколько классов с таким именем, что вы используете правильный.

У меня он унаследован public class CardInfo : ScriptableObject, да и класс такой один. Я уже придумать не могу, в чем может быть проблема

Сработал данный метод:
allCardsList = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<CardInfo>();

